# Когда ввожу в питоне текст, получаеться что путь не правельный

Tags: python

Я ввожу текст,

```
try:
    with open('Test\info.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
```

Чтобы, очевидно зайти в файли и прочитать его, но мне выдаёт

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
    & C:/Users и так далее
```

Как это решать
В конце всё завершено except всё вот это, мне именно не находит файл, только пере создание и спасает, но не всю жизнь же бегать от этого

Comment: Как минимум, обратные слеши в строках нужно экранировать: `'Test\\info.txt'`, или использовать прямые слеши: `'Test/info.txt'`. Во-вторых, пытаться писать какой-то более-менее сложный код в интерактивном режиме - так себе идея. Создайте файл с расширением py, в нем пишите.

Comment: У вас относительный путь указан, поэтому от того из какого каталога запускаете, от того и будет путь составляться

Comment: @insolor. либо использовать \, но в raw-строках :)

Answer (score -2):

В Python в качестве разделителя для пути к файлу используется слэш '/', а не '' (обратный слэш):

```
try:
    with open('Test/info.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        # тут код для работы с файлом
except:
    # тут код для обработки ошибки
```

Если файл с таким именем и в такой директории не существует, то он будет создан автоматически. Если вы хотите создать файл в текущей директории, то можете использовать только имя файла 'info.txt'

Comment: Серьёзно? Каждый язык свой формат пути придумывает?